# Quelle serait une façon plus simple et jolie de formuler la phrase ci-après?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Il y a dorénavant des affiches apposées sur les portes des toilettes d’un bar homosexuel indiquant l’interdiction d’y être deux en même temps/d’être deux dans la cabine à la fois.

Comment: — … l'interdiction d'entrer à deux dans un cabinet. — … « Une personne par cabinet SVP »

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On peut insister sur la simultanéité au moyen de « à la fois » et « en même temps », mais ce n'est pas nécessaire pour que le sens soit clair.

- … indiquant qu'un cabinet ne peut être occupé que par une seule personne.
- … indiquant qu'un cabinet ne peut être occupé que par une seule personne à la fois.
- … indiquant l'interdiction d'occuper un cabinet à deux.
- … indiquant que l'occupation d'un  cabinet à deux est interdite.
- … indiquant que deux personnes ne sont pas autorisées en même temps dans  un cabinet. (*« en même temps » nécessaire dans cette phrase*)

Answer (score 1):

Amis gays, dans la salle d'eau, merci de ne pas pagayer à deux.